# ¿Cómo almaceno en un archivo .csv, una matriz[n][n] de números enteros o decimales en C++?

Tags: c++, c, csv, matrices

Mi problema esta vez es sobre como almacenar una matriz en un archivo .csv para posteriormente hacer ciertos analisis en excel.

Ya se cargar ficheron en la consola y otras cositas pero no he pododido encontrar como almacenar algo en un fichero, en este caso la matriz en el formato .csv

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    cout<<MATRIZ_P[i][j]<<" ";
                }cout<<endl;
            }cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿podrías añadir la declaración de `MATRIZ_P`?

Comment: es una matriz int

Comment: Muy bien que sea una matriz, pero no te he pedido que me digas lo que es, te he pedido que compartas su declaración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generar un fichero CSV no es nada del otro mundo. Simplemente hay que separar los valores de cada fila con una coma:

```
std::ofstream file("test.csv", std::ofstream::out);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    if( j != 0 )
      file << ',';
    file << MATRIZ_P[i][j];
  }
  file << '\n';
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Gracias, es que soy nuevo en esto.